# Wtforms: Best way to split a form across multiple pages?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm dynamically generating a form using WTForms with Flask (based off of a custom form schema), which I'd like to split for UX reasons over multiple pages / refreshes. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to achieve this. My current thinking is the following options:

1. Set all not rendered questions to hidden widgets and somehow handle any validation on them.
2. Reimplement / steal django's form wizard and dynamic section up the form into many smaller forms.

I'm going to have to add some sort of concept of sections into the Meta of the form class to handle the layout abstraction but I'm perplexed as to which of the two options (or others I haven't thought of) might be the best way to achieve the web UX?

If these were hard coded forms, I'd just have one form per page and handle the interim logic in the view, but I need to be able to dynamically generate them unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying too hard to make HTTP into a stateful protocol when it was designed to be a [stateless protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)

Your best bet is to hide the fact that there are two steps from the server. Just show two different pages to the user and keep the input values in memory until you have all of them and can send them to the server.

You haven't said which technology you're using for the UX btw, but this is a classic HTTP problem which is best solved on the frontend.

Comment: Extra context: Flask / WTForms python web application with custom html / js /css designed to support older browsers and be accessible to all. Hence, I can't use something like Angular / React / Jquery here. I think you're right, I may have to use signed cookies / template variables to secure the data before final submit.